# Using Smach and SimpleActionState

Tags: actionlib, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some questions about using SimpleActionState with Smach:

- How does one define/set the action as succeeded, preempted, or aborted? Or is this set in the actionlib server using set_succeeded, etc.?
- If this is set using the actionlib server can I still have a custom outcome? If yes, how?
- Do I still need to define a new class or function to handle the states or do I just have to add the states (using StateMachine.add)?
- Do I need to manually run actionlib servers or is this automatically run by smach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9393/using-smach-and-simpleactionstate/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How does one define/set the action as succeeded, preempted, or aborted? Or is this set in the actionlib server using set_succeeded, etc.?

I've not used SMACH with actions, but I have been using SMACH quite a bit with services. I believe the implementations are similar, in which case you'd get the outcomes from the action server. If you wanted custom outcomes, you'd probably have to write your own state.

> Do I still need to define a new class or function to handle the states or do I just have to add the states (using StateMachine.add)?

If you use the SimpleActionState, then no, you do not need to define a new class. You do have to create an instance of the SimpleActionState class and in the process fill in a few details (namely the name of the service, what goal to supply, and what states to transition to on each outcome).

> Do I need to manually run actionlib servers or is this automatically run by smach?

Yes, you'll need to start them manually (a launch file might be handy here).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2